# Synonym for "for the time being"

Tags: synonyms, american-english

I'm writing an email and I want to ask them (Career Development Office) if there are any volunteering opportunities for the time being.

But, the way I wrote it in the actual message doesn't really match with saying "for the time being". I'm looking to say that in a more proper and formal way.

The meaning I want to go for is something along the lines of "temporarily" or "for this period" or "currently".

Are there any suggestions?

---

For the time being = a bit informal

Temporarily = sounds as if you are not serious enough and only looking to volunteer for an hour and then give up

Momentarily = ? sounds like you couldn't come up with a better wording

For the moment = for just ONE MOMENT ???

---

seems like I cannot come up with the word to describe in a literal and formal, at the same time, way what I am looking for.

I want to say something along the lines of:
**I am available now, and in the near future, but after that, not anymore.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if there's something **now**, I'd just say "at the moment".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20moment

If you're saying that there is a short time where you are available, then I would be specific about when that period ends.

Eg

> Are there any volunteering opportunities at the moment?  I am
> available until the end of October 2020.

Comment: Thank you Max. I know it was easy but sometimes I rush too quickly to send emails and either make plenty spelling/grammar mistakes, or just phrase things oddly.

Comment: "As it is,..." if used can refer to not just time, but other reasons also.

Answer (score 1):

You might say the [***nonce***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonce). (M/W) has it as "for the time being" and "the ... present occasion, purpose, or use "

Comment: If I said that I dont think I would ever get a response back from them